# Where is the logout option in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface, user-accounts

How do I logout from an account?

I don't see the logout option and I can't figure how I enter the site, because when I visit the page (in Chrome) the login is made automatically.

Comment: If you sign in with a google account it will automatically log you in, using google chrome. There are options to switch this off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is*:

[image]

The automatic logon is because you did not logout from that particularly device.

<sub>*Credits to @Matte, for pointing this out with a comment.</sub>

Comment: In nearly five years, I don't think I've ever logged out.

Comment: Usually, in other sites this option is at the top right side with other account options. And if we usually just go to a community, it's difficult to find the location of the log out in that place.

Comment: I see Stack Overflow has a new top bar, where the log out is indeed at the upper right side. All other communities I participate are equal as written in this answer. But it is not so difficult to find it, imo. @CarlosPires